# Updating MS Access database structure with new Database structure

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am working on VB.NET which using an MS Access database. I want to deploy new database with new tables and column changes.

How to update existing database strcture with new database. while preserving values to existing database. i.e. add new tables, adding fields etc.

Is there any way I can do this? so I can give updates to the application and deploy updates for my application?

Many Thanks

Comment: *measure twice, cut once*  if the changes are substantial you will have to write queries to migrate the data from one to another (ie myTable to myTable1).  If they are more minor you just need update queries.

Comment: To make changes to the database schema, you execute the appropriate SQL statements, e.g. `ALTER TABLE`.  To execute a SQL statement that doesn't create a result set in VB you call `ExecuteNonQuery` on an appropriate command object.  As suggested by Plutonix, if the changes are significant then you may need to do things like create temporary tables to store the data as you modify the tables.

Comment: Thanks, I understood, can you please share some example code to achieve this?, Thanks again for your time and concern.